# How to simplify this switch statement (Angular app)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-service

I'm using a modalService to store modal templates in my mainController.

Here is how I store them (from mainController)

```
// Store popup modal:
$ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl('app/popup/popup.html', {})
.then(function(modal) {
    PopupFactory.storeModal(modal);
});

// Store addTicker modal:
$ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl('app/tickers/addTicker.html', {})
.then(function(modal) {
    ModalFactory.storeModal('addTicker', modal);
});
```

#### modalFactory

This is what the `storeModal` function looks like:

```
function storeModal(type, modal) {
    switch(type) {
        case 'addTicker':
            vm.addTicker = modal;
            break;
        case 'addTag':
            vm.addTag = modal;
            break;
    }
}
```

^ as you can see I have to create an object for each modal my app will have.

This is what the getModal function looks like:

```
function getModal(type) {
    switch(type) {
        case 'addTicker':
            return vm.addTicker;
            break;
        case 'addTag':
            return vm.addTag;
            break;
        case 'anotherModal':
            return vm.anotherModal;
            break;
        case 'yetAnotherModal':
            return vm.yetAnotherModal;
            break;
    }
}
```

**I feel like this code can be optimized to 1 or 2 lines...**

---

I've tried the follow to no avail:

```
function getModal(type) {
    return vm.+type;
}
```

and

```
function getModal(type) {
    var returned = type;
    return vm.returned;
}
```

However when I call getModal in the respective Directive Controllers, I get undefined:

```
function addTickerButton() {
    vs.addTicker = ModalFactory.getModal('addTicker');
    vs.addTicker.show('addTicker);
    $rootScope.$emit("modal.add.tickers");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got very close here:

```
function getModal(type) {
    var returned = type;
    return vm.returned;
}
```

But you are trying to access a `returned` attribute on `vm`, which doesn't exist. To retrieve an attribute using a variable, you must use bracket notation:

```
function getModal(type) {
    return vm[type];
}
```

Comment: Thanks! And thx for the explanation, I knew it was something like this, but the syntax was escaping me...

Answer (score 1):

Just do

```
function getModal(type) {
    return vm[type];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What you need is an object accessor with bracket notation:

```
vm[type] = modal
```

See [this link](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors) for more details.